# how to determine that user or operating system has changed registry key?

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I have a small app which monitors registry key changing and it works fine. But i wanna know when registry change, registry has changed by user or operating system? Can i do that?

Comment: There's no real bright-line distinction here - what do you classify as a user change? That it was done by an application that the user was using? That they used regedit directly? That they used a third-party registry editing tool? And an OS change? Only by the kernel? Or by regedit too? Or only by code running under the `SYSTEM` account?

Comment: as user : all of you said.
as os : without System Account.

Actually i want to monitor user. Does user chage registry or registry changed because of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **WMI RegistryKeyChanged event**. Check the MSDN documentation here: [RegistryKeyChangeEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For more registry change monitoring check the [WMI Registry Event Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).